# Laravel 4 View::share( ) only after auth filtering

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have some user data I need to share with all views, a list of 'types' owned by the user. I have setup a view::share to accomplish this, and placed it inside my routes.php inside an 'auth' filtered group like so:

`routes.php`

```
/* Authenticated group */
Route::group( array('before' => 'auth'), function() {

    // Bring list of user's Types into views for sidebar menu generation
    View::share( 'types', User::find( Auth::user()->id )->types );

    /* Some user routes */

});
```

This works properly when the user is logged in, however when they are logged out it throws `Trying to get property of non-object` error. Am I misunderstanding how route filtering works? I'm guessing this `View::share` is still being processed even though it is inside the 'auth' filtered route group.

What is the proper way to do this? Should I create a `Route::filter` to share the data and then apply it to the route group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to just share the variable in your filters instead.

Assuming you use Laravel's default auth filters (in `filters.php`):

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) {
        View::share('types', 'not_logged_in');
        return Redirect::guest('login');
    }
    else {
        View::share('types', User::find( Auth::user()->id )->types);
        // If you are not returning anything, this filter passes
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because `Auth::user()` returns non-object when not logged in. Need to account for this.

```
if ( Auth::check() ){
    View::share( 'types', User::find( Auth::user()->id )->types );
} else {
    View::share( 'types', $some_other_types_here );
}
```

Comment: That is what I figured, but I thought that auth filtering was doing `Auth::check()`?

Comment: Also, is it incorrect to put this sort of Auth check logic inside my routes?